# PHP on several servers with session-sharing

Tags: php, load-balancing, memcached, redis

there's certanly other threads about this, but I have one more question.

We are about to scale the website at work to have more than one server. And we *need* to share the sessions between the servers.

We have been looking into different solutions, one in *memcached* and use Memcached as sessionhandler in PHP. That will probably work.

And the idea would be to run memcached on every machine and let all webservers access all other servers memcached servers, and then we have shared sessions between the machines, yay. (we have no resources to setup with sticky-sessions yet, that's a later project. we need this running, and we need this running now. and we will loadbalance with DNS for a starter)

But then... If I want to take one server down, say, for maintenance, or a server crashes, or whatever reason. I don't want the users to just loose their sessions and have to start from the beginning... That's why we need some kind of replication, which Memcached does not support.

Then I found http://repcached.lab.klab.org/ -- which has multi-master replication of memcached, which is great, and is what I want. But does it work with >2 machines? Say 3, 5, 10? For future scaling.

I also looked into redishttp://redis.io/ -- which also seems great, but is a bit more "shaky" with the php-session-handler support, and no multi-master-replication.

The thing is that I like to use memcached, but I want to be able to power down one of two boxes without loosing half of the sessions. Any suggestions?

Comment: And, I found this today: http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.ini.php

The memcache module, there's also the memcached module, the memcache module can set the variable _memcache.session_redundancy_ in php.ini and it will do exactly what I need, with sessions.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at couchdb which implements replicated key store with a memcache API. It also handles overflow of the memory storage more gracefully than most memcache implementations (a likely outcome during failover). I must admit that I'm not familiar with the details of how it implements replication.

All the implementations of 'sticky' sessions I've seen bind the request to an explicit device - which does not make for good failover - and with PHP the session affinity is only relevant to the storage substrate (unlike in Java where it usually needs to be at the logic tier). So using sticky sessions at the HTTP tier is irrelevant.

Certainly using asynchronous MySQL replication in the substrate is not trivial due to replication lag and single thread write operations - I use a connection broker in PHP (which implements preference and blocks during failover) to address this. Although MySQL is not the most efficient solution for session handling, if your applications are already relying on a high-availability relational database, then it makes a lot of sense to use it for session storage. There are multi-master replication implementations for MySQL - e.g. Percona.

MongoDB also uses asynch replication, but without the single thread dependency of MySQL.

You're going to have to spend some time thinking about how you fence nodes. Virtual address takeover (if implemented correctly) should make the operation transparent, but IME it can be tricky to get right and it needs to takeover the arp address as well as the IP address to avoid big pauses during failover.

> Say 3, 5, 10? For future scaling

If you're planning to scale to this extent, then you should probably be thinking about multiple data centres - which implies a synchronization method which can cope with low bandwidth / higher latency i.e. not a shared filesystem.

Comment: Couchdb might be interesting, havent looked into it yet. And well, we will run some kind of Mysql, probably Percona. But we want to keep the sessions out of mysql, we store lots of data in our sessions, and alter the contents quite much. That's why memorycaching is of interest, and we plan to keep the session maybe two days, max seven days I think. But a servercrash can come at any time, and it would be very sad if the session died douring checkout of the customer or something.

Comment: Keeping sessions open that long means you're going to need lots of resources just to manage the sessions - would a 'remeber me' facility be more appropriate? If not then you should definitely be looking at large capacity / non-volatile storage for the sessions. It sounds like your storing transactional data in the session - which is a really bad idea - it might seem like an easy fix but unless your code is rather complex you're going to run into horrible problems later.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a [database session handler](http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database) instead of memcached. You probably do use a database anyway and if your database is down then your site is down too, so you do not add new failure modes.

Memcached does not handle failover. Cache invalidation in such multiple master environments in any system is either slow and complicated (synchronous) or unreliable (asynchronous). So you'll have situations that you set some session variable on one server and next request goes to another server, which has old value of this variable.

Comment: Yes, I like memcached as idea, but the failover-part is the hard part that I don't realy like that it doesn't handle well in this kind of setup.Sure a reboot of the one server today means that we drop all sessions, but... with two servers it makes no sense to drop everything or half. What do you think about Repcached? Can it do the job? Have anyone heard about it before?